# generate random sample with in a range but with different size each time in python

Tags: python-3.x

Ex: Assume we have `[1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,11 ,12 ,13]`
for the first sample we will select
`[3, 4, 5, 9, 1, 2]`
and for the second sample `[7, 9, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2]`
and so on
Make sure each sample will have at least 3 elements

Answer (score 2):

### Don't ask people to write code for you on SO.

With that said:

```
import random
def select_sample(arr,minsize):
    size = random.randrange(minsize,len(arr))
    return [random.choice(arr) for i in range(size)]
```